# Textarea Readonly + Select iOs Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, mobile

So I'm trying to auto select all the text within a textarea on click. Here's my code:

```
<textarea class="donger" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);" readonly="readonly">Testing</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvy37tyc/

This works fine in iOS Safari, however it doesn't work in iOS Chrome. If I remove the readonly it works in both browsers but unfortunately then it brings up the keyboard which covers half the screen.

I tried this to remove the keyboard, but unfortunately it disables the auto select:

```
$('.donger').blur();
```

**Question**
So does anybody have any ideas that I could select the text on click on mobile without having the keyboard come up?